# Audio Frame Repetition when combining audio clips in moviepy

Tags: audio, ffmpeg, moviepy

Audio frames at very end of a clip get repeated when I concatenate two or more video clips.

I tinkered with

1. buffer size (writing with audio_buffsize = 1000 works fine for now)
2. duration ( because I observed that for a clip with 43.15 sec of audio, final video get rounded to 44.0 which adds some glitch / last frame buffer repetition (I guess) = 44.0-43.15.)

> com_vid.write_videofile(FINAL_OUT_VID,
> fps=1,
> codec="libx264",
> audio_bitrate='192k',
> audio_fps=44100,
> audio_nbytes=2,
> audio_codec="aac",
> audio_bufsize=1000)  # fix issue for audio glitches.

writing with audio_buffsize = 1000 works fine for now. But I am not sure whether it will work for every case. I need to write one long clips with many small clips hence need some advice/pointers on how to get cohesive result/clip.

Waveform: this is the case when above code breaks and glitches appear again.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Pip was installing `1.0.3` version somehow. Upgrading to latest version fixed the issue.

Comment: I don't understand. Isn't moviepy==1.0.3 the most recent version?

Comment: on github release page